# Is it a best practice to have nested setState in React?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

```
setState({}, ()=> {setState({})};
```

I have a requirement where I need to clear myMessage before rendering with actual message.

```
someHandler () {
 setState({
  myMessage: null
  }, () => {
  setState({
   myMessage: <p>this is my new message</p>
  });
 });
}

render () {
 return (
  <div>
   {this.state.myMessage}
  </div>
 )
}
```

I couldn't find any issue with React Lifecycle but would like to know if this could be an anti-pattern or any negative impacts.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need to clear your state before setting it. It sounds a lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153542).

Comment: Though it is not wrong but i dont understand the need of this here.

Comment: Currently I have a live region (aria-live) which needs to updated in order for a screen-reader to announce the change. The use case is to notify users with form-validation errors. Just setting the state once will update the message to be announced, but if the same message needs to be announced again, the first error-message needs to be cleared before we can add another error-message, in order to update the aria-live region.I have tried ARIA methods such as role='alert', role='log', aria-atomic, and aria-relevant but to no avail.

Comment: First, this look like messy code. Try to achive it in other way, for example, setState in render when you detect that state.myMessage is null. Second, I can tell you for sure that store html/React components in state is bad practice.

Comment: `<p>this is my new message</p>` is html with content. You should save information in the state. Use the render method to generate markup. If you need conditional rendering you can do this. `<div>{this.state.myMessage && <p>{this.state.myMessage}</p>}</div>`

Comment: "but if the same message needs to be announced again" I think the issue is, if you update the state with the same message as before, the screen-reader will not detect any change and will be silent. Technically if you update the state with the same message, the DOM will not change. I would look for ways to ensure the DOM is changed somehow if the message should be the same as before. Could be setting random not used attribute to the html element to update DOM or some other similar trick, to make the screen-reader detect a change. `<p data-random="13213">this is my new message</p>`